# Cross-Domain iframe cookie authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, cookies, iframe, cross-domain

I`m creating web-app which have to integrate 3rd-party system and provide seamless authentication process: my app stores credentials for both systems.
The problem is that 3rd-party system is embeed in my app using iframe, but it requires authentication and does not have any API for it - the only way to authenticate is to store cookie, received by form submission.

In backend I can't do it - cookies have different domain and is not supported.

I'm trying to implement following scenario:
when user is authenticated in my app I render a html page, which:

1. send Cross-Domain AJAX-post and submits auth form
2. when form submission completed successfully - sets 'src' attribute of iframe and renders secured content from 3rd-party system.

Of course, that system has headers Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*' and  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true

Will it work? What other options do I have?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this will work, but users may get a prompt from their browser to confirm for step 2.